# CakePHP: Pagination with query constraints on related hasMany field?

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694047/cakephp-pagination-with-conditions-on-has-many) — but due to my ineptitude with CakePHP, I can't seem to figure this out. Here is my setup.

I've got a model name `User` which has many `Comments`. I want a list of all invisible `Users` with at least one `Comment`. Our controller has methods set up to set `records` as `$this->paginate()` without any values passed to it; instead, the `$paginate` var is set up with conditions and things like that.

```
class UsersController extends AppController {
    var $name = 'Users';
    var $paginate;

    function new_users() {
        $this->User->recursive = 1;
        $this->paginate['User']['contain'][] = 'Comment';
        $this->paginate['User']['order'] = 'User.DateCreated DESC';

        $conditions = array();
        // Get invisible users...
        $conditions[] = array('User.Status = ?' => 'Invisible');
        $conditions[] = array('User.Enabled' => true);
        // ...with at least one active comment
        $conditions[] = array('Comment.Status' => 'Active');

        // Load these conditions and fire pagination to render the view
        $this->paginate['User']['conditions'] = $conditions;
        $this->set('records', $this->paginate());
    }
}
```

I am so new to CakePHP that a lot of this stuff is still over my head. I just want a list of `Users` that have active `Comments`. Right now, *this query nets me 0 users*. If I take out the line regarding `Comment.Status`, the query goes through, but I get all invisible `Users` regardless of if they have comments.

Everywhere online that I've seen the `paginate()` call, things have been passed to it (like `paginate('User', array('Comment.Status' => 'Active'))`, which I've tried and nets me nothing).

**Edit**: I've got the following code, while cleaner, still gives me the same results.

```
$this->paginate = array(
  'conditions' => array(
    'User.Status' => 'Invisible',
    'User.Enabled' => true,
  ),
  'contain' => array(
    'Comment' => array(
      'conditions' => array(
        'Comment.Status' => 'Active',
      )
    )
  ),
  'recursive' => 1,
  'order' => 'User.DateCreated DESC',
);
$data = $this->paginate('User');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use the paginate changes on-the-fly hehe. Here is some example code.

```
$this->paginate = array(
    'conditions' => array('Recipe.title LIKE' => 'a%'),
    'limit' => 10    );
$data = $this->paginate('Recipe');
```

[Here](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1232/Controller-Setup) you can read more about controller setup for paginations. But if you already have the associations in the model (hasMany, etc) the data is auto-fetched if you put recursive to 1 without the need of contain (you may still use it to get only the data you want). an example of how it will look for you:

```
$this->paginate = array(
    'conditions' => array(
         'User.Status' => 'Invisible',
         'User.Enabled' => true
    ),
    'contain' => array('Comment' => array(
           'conditions' => array('Comment.Status' => 'Active')
    )),
    'recursive' => 1,
    'order' => 'User.DateCreated DESC'
);
$data = $this->paginate('User');
```

This is what you put in your post. If you paste the sql query of what you want, I may be able to help you more. Also, try checking the sql output so you know if something is wrong in the conditions. if you don't have and don't know how to put the sql output just do this.

```
var_dump($this->User->getQuery(
    'conditions' => array(
         'User.Status' => 'Invisible',
         'User.Enabled' => true,
         'Comment.Status' => 'Active'
    ),
    'contain' => 'Comment',
    'order' => 'User.DateCreated DESC'
));
```

Hope it helps you, if not, leave me a comment.

**EDIT**: This is what you need to do to get what you want. :D Change the table and the condition to fit your needs.

```
$this->paginate = array(
    'conditions' => array(
         'User.Status' => 'Invisible',
         'User.Enabled' => true
    ),
    'joins' =>  array(
        array(
          'table' => 'name_of_comment_table',
          'alias' => 'Comment',
          'type' => 'inner',
          'conditions' => array(
              'Comment.user_id = User.id',
              'Comment.Status' => 'Active'
           )
         )
     ),
    'contains' => array('Comment'),
    'group' => 'User.id',
    'recursive' => 1,
    'order' => 'User.DateCreated DESC'
);
$data = $this->paginate('User');
```

Comment: With your help, I'm getting close. I can't seem to access my data in my view. I'm using `$this->set('records', $data)` -- and my pagination count seems accurate (I'm getting 1300+ records counted in my view) -- but I can't seem to access `$records` (there doesn't seem to be anything in there) in my view.

Comment: @BenjaminKreeger try var_dumo($data) before sending to the view, so we know if it is fetching the data or not... (remember to use the code from paginate and not getQuery the last just return the query without doing it)

Comment: Doing a `var_dump($this->paginate('User'))` shows `bool(false)`, so something is going on. I setup `$this->paginate = ` just as you showed in your answer. I'm about ready to throw this thing out the window.

Comment: @BenjaminKreeger quick question, are you setting the contain component in app_controller? (or in the user controller) try doing the getQuery one just to check that it is returning the correct query (correct query means it processed all conditions, limit, etc we use.

Comment: I change it, i made a mistake, sorry :S try it again, and post your results. Hope it works now :D

Comment: With the revised query, it shows my data in the view (with cleaner behind-the-scenes code, I may add, thank you), but I'm still getting new Invisible users with no comments. I'll revise my code samples.

Comment: well, actually the hasMany association fetches first the users and then dos a query for each user tu fetch the comments... to get exactly what you want instead of contain use join im editing the post to show you, also you may use the component linkable, though it is a little outdated it works fine ;)

Comment: I've got an updated solution: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3669/discussion-between-benjamin-kreeger-and-api55)